# How to return correct status code when enumeration of IEnumerable fails. ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-web-api

NOTE: The following problem happens only during testing of the controller. Here is refined question [How to properly integration test Web Api controller with IEnumerable results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31451966/how-to-properly-integration-test-web-api-controller-with-ienumerable-results)

Is there any way to avoid calling ToList method but still return correct status code in case of exception from deferred LINQ execution to keep controllers as simple as possible?

E.g. I have such API endpoint:

```
public class EntityController : ApiController
{
    ...
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(Session.Query<Entity>());
    }
}
```

Above code will always return successful status code, but with ToList it will not be successful in case of any trouble executing the query.

```
public class EntityController : ApiController
{
    ...
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(Session.Query<Entity>().ToList());
    }
}
```

The reason why it work like that is clear, but is there any smarter way to return proper status code and keep controller simple?

Comment: The first example would return a `500 - Internal Server Error` if there is an issue with the query, the exception will just occur at a different point in the pipeline, Most likely when the serializer enumerates the IEnumerable.

Comment: Yes, @AnishPatel, you are actually right and I need to refine the question. The problem happens when I'm trying to integration test this controller against database and for some reason the whole pipeline is not executed and status code is 200 in nay case.

Comment: Please check refined question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31451966/how-to-properly-integration-test-web-api-controller-with-ienumerable-results

Comment: Please see [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31453565/1062224) to your re framed question.

Answer (score 0):

You could debug the action, then look what exception gets thrown.

Then you can easily try-catch this line of code and if if fails, you give something different then 500 back.

```
try
{
    return //...;
}
catch (//your Exception)
{
    return //... As Example BadRequest or something different
}
```

Hope it helps.